# Dividing a long list of Widgets into multiple pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have a list of widgets as follows :

```
List<Widget> widgets = [Row(1), Row(2), Row(3), ...... Row(30)];
```

Now I want to divide this list into multiple pages. Something like this :

```
PageView(
  children: [
      Page1(),  // lets say this page contains rows 1 to 7
      Page2(),  // lets say this page contains rows 8 to 13
      Page3(),  // this contains the remaining rows 14 - 30
   ]
)
```

Now this would have been somewhat easy to solve if all the rows were of same height.
But in my case, the heights of the row can vary.

The issue is I have no idea about how many rows to fit in each page as flutter doesn't provide any good way to calculate the height of a widget.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Make a Container with fixed maximum height then put Center as a child which has a Row as it's child, nest it like this:  Container(height:maxHeight child: Center(child:Row()))

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, maybe you don't need separate pages.
I guess something like this would help:

```
var rowSet1 = [Row(), Row(), Row()]; 
var rowSet2 = [Row(), Row(), Row()];
var rowSet3 = [Row(), Row(), Row()];

var pageView = PageView(children: [
  ...rowSet1,
  ...rowSet2,
  ...rowSet3
]);
```

You can even split it into separate files, but just reference/import it and use in the file where you need it.

You can make a `RowWrapper` widget that would receive `Row` as a child, but it would be wrapped with a `Container` with fixed height or `IntrinsicHeight` (if you want to let the framework decide the height).

Comment: The issue is I have no idea about how many rows to fit in each page as flutter doesn't provide any good way to calculate the height of a widget

Comment: You can use something like `IntrinsicHeight` with `addPostFrameCallback` and in this method, you would get the exact dimensions of your widget.
The problem here is that `IntrinsicHeight` is quite an expensive widget for rendering, but probably that would depend on your layout.
More here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html and here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html